# Limit WebSphere MQ transmission speed

Tags: ibm-mq

I have two network zones devided by a firewall. In the two zones there are QMs that exchange messages. Now I would like to add other two QMs, on each side one, that would serve for transferring non-critical messages such as logging events. Not to saturate the firewall, I would like to limit the speed between these two new QMs.

Is it possible to finetune maximum speed of the MQ Channels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to finetune maximum speed of the MQ Channels?

No.  But there is an add on product called [MQ Channel Throttler](http://www.capitalware.com/mqct_overview.html) that will do it.

Answer (score 2):

To throttle the speed of a channel requires a channel exit if you want the throttling to happen in the MQ layer rather than in the network layer. Roger's answer is one such example of a channel exit.